# Condition for largest eigenvalue being strictly larger than largest variance

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Under which condition is the largest eigenvalue of a positive semi-definite matrix strictly larger than the largest of the matrix's diagonal entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that there's a nice necessary and sufficient condition, but a sufficient condition is that  at least one off-diagonal entry in the row with the largest diagonal entry is nonzero.

EDIT: Let your matrix by $A$.  Suppose the largest diagonal entry is $d_{ii}$ and $d_{ij} \ne 0$.
Consider the $2 \times 2$ submatrix consisting of the $i$'th and $j$'th row and column.  This is also positive semidefinite; if $p(\lambda)$ is its 
characteristic polynomial, $p(d_{ii}) = -d_{ij}^2 < 0$, while of course $p(\lambda) \to +\infty$, so there must be a root $\mu$ of $p$ greater than $d_{ii}$.  This translates to there being a nonzero vector $u$ having only its $i$'th and $j$'th entries nonzero such that
$\langle A u, u \rangle =  \mu \langle u, u \rangle$, and then the largest
eigenvalue of $A$ is at least $\mu$.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\lambda_{max} =  
\max_{|v|=1} \langle Av, v\rangle
$$

Comment: But this only gives me an inequality.  How do I get that the largest eigenvalue is strictly larger than the largest variance entry of the matrix?

Comment: it is not strictly larger. consider a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Yes, generally not.  Robert Israel gave one condition on when we have a strict inequality.