# Sufficient condition for positive definite matrix to be bounded above from its maximum eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

> Assume that $\;f \in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^n ; \mathbb R)\;$ and that
>   the matrix $\frac {{\partial}^2 f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\;$ is
>   positive definite for $\;a \in A \subset \mathbb R^n\;$.

Since the matrix is positive definite , I know that all the eigenvalues are positive.This is sufficient in order to claim that the eigenvalues satisfy: $\;0\le λ_1 \le λ_2 \le \dots \le λ_n \;$.

**Question:** How can I show that $\frac {{\partial}^2 f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\le λ_n\;\;\forall i,j\;$

I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advnace!!!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256367/condition-for-largest-eigenvalue-being-strictly-larger-than-largest-variance might be of interest, but both do not fully anwer your question.

Comment: If $A >0$ and symmetric then $\|A\| = \lambda_\max(A)$, so $|A_{ij}| = |e_i^T A e_j| \le \|A\|$. Note that the $ij$ entry may be strictly negative.

Comment: @copper.hat The norm you used above, is the spectral norm right? I didn't fully understand the last sentence.. it holds $\;1\le i,j \le n\;$

Comment: The induced 2 norm. It is true that $A_{ij} \le \|A\|$, but this is vacuous if $A_{ij} < 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Since $\;A \gt 0\;$ , could $\;A_{ij} \lt 0\;$? It may be quite elementary what I asked but matrices aren't my thing...

Comment: Sure, $A=\begin{bmatrix} 10 & -1 \\ -1 & 10 \end{bmatrix}$ is positive definite but has negative entries.

Comment: @copper.hat You're right. What a silly I am. Well I also know that $\;f\;$ is a non-negative function (I ommited from above) and by Taylor expansion I could write $f(x)= {1\over2}\sum_{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\left({\partial^2 f\over\partial x_i\partial x_j}\right)_0 (x_i-a)(x_j-a)\; + o({\vert x-a \vert}^2)\;$. Is this enough in order to avoid the obstacle you mentioned?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The function $f(x) = x^T A x$ (where $A$ is as above) is a non negative function whose Hessian is positive definite but some of the entries in $A$ are negative.

Comment: $f$ being non-negative does not in any way restrict its partial derivatives of any order from being negative. $e^{-x}$ has a negative derivative everywhere (though admittedly, it's 2nd derivative is positive).